# Python でtext file 内の英文を読み取ってキーワードにのっとって文を種類分けするとき、コード内のlistを読み取りません

Tags: python

Pythonを勉強している初心者です。
以下のコードで、text file内の英文を読み取って、statement（命題）として成立する文かそうじゃないかを分別するプログラムを練習で作っているのですが、分別する際のキーワードを並べた2行目のlistが21行目のelif構文内でうまく機能していないようです。
どうして動かないのか、どうすれば正しく動作するか、もしよろしければ教えて下さい。

使ったtext file　の内容

```
Strawberries are fruit.
Do you like grape jelly?
The Church is true.
She sings well.
2 + 2 = 5
how are you doing
Go.
School is located in Japan
```

コード内容

```py
from sys import argv


qWord = ["what","where","how","why","who","when","he","she","it","they"]

if len (argv) == 1:
    print ("Type argument/filename.") 
else:
    filename = argv[1]
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            contents = file.read()
    except IOError:
        print("No File Found")
    else:

        file = open(filename)
   #process to open the file


        for line in file: 
            line = line.rstrip()

            if line[-1] == "?":
                print(line+" NOT A STATEMENT")

            elif " " not in line: 
                print(line+" NOT A STATEMENT")

            elif line in qWord:
                print(line+" NOT A STATEMENT")
            else:
                print(line+" STATEMENT")
```

コマンドライン内で本来の趣旨に則って動作した場合の反応

```
Strawberries are fruit. STATEMENT
Do you like grape jelly? NOT A STATEMENT
The Church is true. STATEMENT
She sings well. NOT A STATEMENT
2 + 2 = 5 STATEMENT
how are you doing NOT A STATEMENT
Go. NOT A STATEMENT
School is located in Japan STATEMENT
```

実際の反応

```
Strawberries are fruit. STATEMENT
Do you like grape jelly? NOT A STATEMENT
The Church is true. STATEMENT
She sings well. STATEMENT
2 + 2 = 5 STATEMENT
how are you doing STATEMENT
Go. NOT A STATEMENT
School is located in Japan STATEMENT
```

Comment: qWord に含まれるかどうかを判定するためには line を word に分解する必要がありますので、`elif line in qWord:` の部分は、例えば `elif any([word.lower() in qWord for word in line.split(' ')]):` の様になるでしょう(単純にスペースで分割しているだけなので不完全かもしれません)。

Comment: 教えて下さった方法で試したところ、エラーメッセージが出ましたが、それを少しアレンジして　`any(word in line for word in qWord):`　という形にしてプログラム走らせたところ無事動作しました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: その方が良いですね(私の書き方は冗長ですね…)。よろしければ回答を書いてみて下さい。

Comment: 返信遅れてすみません。回答はこのコメント欄に記入すればよろしいでしょうか？それともページの下に見える「質問に回答する」の中に回答すればいいでしょうか？

Comment: はい、「質問に回答する」の方にお願いします。また、自己回答でも承認する事が可能です。

Comment: 分かりました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

頂いたアドバイスを元に無事動作したコードを下記に載せます。
助けて下さりありがとうございました！

```py
from sys import argv

questionSig = '?'
space = ' '
qWord = ["what","where","how","why","who","when","he","she","it","they"]

if len (argv) == 1:
    print ("Type argument/filename.") 
else:
    filename = argv[1]
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            contents = file.read()
    except IOError:
        print("No File Found")
    else:

        file = open(filename)
   #process to open the file



        for line in file: 
            line = line.rstrip()


            if any(word in line for word in qWord):
                print(line+" NOT A STATEMENT")


            elif " " not in line: 
                print(line+" NOT A STATEMENT")

            elif line[-1] == "?":
                print(line+" NOT A STATEMENT")
            else:
                print(line+" STATEMENT")
```